# Dynamically update table using Dynamic LINQ

Tags: entity-framework-6, dynamic-linq, entity-framework-plus, entity-framework-extensions, dynamic-linq-core

I have a list of column names and I want to dynamically update table and set all the rows for those columns to NULL. The current code is using `if` logic and it need to keep updating when list of columns changes

```
var columns = new string[] {"FirstName","LastName"};
using(var scope = new TransactionScope())
{
     foreach(var col in columns)
     {
       if(col == "FirstName")
       {
          dbContext.Users
                .Where(x=>x.ParentID = 1234)
                .Update(x=> new User()
                { 
                   FirstName = null
                }
       }

       if(col == "LastName")
       {
          dbContext.Users
                .Where(x=>x.ParentID = 1234)
                .Update(x=> new User()
                { 
                   LastName = null
                }
       }   
     
     }

     scope.Complete();
}
```

I am also using [Dynamic LINQ](https://dynamic-linq.net/) and [Z Framework](https://entityframework-plus.net/) with EF 6. Is there a way to update table certain columns dynamically?
*(I can also construct sql update string execute as CommandText but I am trying to avoid that)*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Disclaimer**: I'm the owner of the project [Entity Framework Plus](https://entityframework-plus.net/)

The `UpdateFromQuery` similar to `Update` from EF Extensions allow to uses `ExpandoObject` and `IDictionary<string, object>`

For example:

```
Dictionary<string, object> dict = new Dictionary<string, object>();
dict.Add("FirstName", null);

dbContext.Users
        .Where(x=>x.ParentID = 1234)
        .UpdateFromQuery(dict);
```

Next week, the `Update` method will also support it, I will update my answer at this time.

**UPDATED**

Since the [v5.1.29](https://github.com/zzzprojects/EntityFramework-Plus/releases/tag/v5.1.29), the `Update` method also support dictionary

```
Dictionary<string, object> dict = new Dictionary<string, object>();
dict.Add("FirstName", null);

dbContext.Users
        .Where(x=>x.ParentID = 1234)
        .Update(dict);
```